# How can i calculate the sum the values inside a child node in firebase realtime database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is the code i am trying.I want to add data to child node ***result*** and to show the sum of those values :

```
 FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference databaseReference1 = firebaseDatabase1.getReference("Sumofcal").child("result");

    ValueEventListener valueEventListener1 = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1) {

            String itsme = String.valueOf(Objects.requireNonNull(dataSnapshot1.getValue()));

            Log.i("child", String.valueOf(itsme));

            int sum = 0;

            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot1.getChildren()) {
                sum = Integer.parseInt(sum + itsme);
            }


        }


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };
    databaseReference1.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener1);
```

This is the logcat output:

```
 java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0{-LSxVZ3hsemUKAYOh0Gn= 95, -LSxVZnx5Bhv2C33_lk-= 10, -LSxVNYT0BJDytRaFXzb= 16}"
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:521)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:556)
    at com.example.itsandpro.Signup.Api.SearchAdapter$2.onDataChange(SearchAdapter.java:135)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:75)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:63)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:55)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

i have realtime database setup like this. I wanted to seperate the pushId from the number and do summition af all the values.

```
    Sumofcal
result
-LSxVNYT0BJDytRaFXzb: 
" 16"
-LSxVZ3hsemUKAYOh0Gn: 
" 95"
-LSxVZnx5Bhv2C33_lk-: 
" 10"
```

Comment: Please replace the links to images with the actual text from those images. In the case of the database structure, you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in the overflow menu (⠇) of [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the actual text as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data/code and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this, please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference resultRef = rootRef.child("Sumofcal").child("result");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        int total = 0;
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            int number = Integer.valueOf(ds.getValue(String.class).replaceAll(" ", ""));
            total = total + number;
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "total= " + total);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
resultRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The result in your logcat will be:

```
total= 121
```

Btw, I strongly recommend you to use numbers and **not** Strings when creating a sum. Also be aware of the space that exist inside your values:

```
    " 16"
//   ^
```

Comment: You beat me in this answer by 17 seconds :)